# Angular 5 select elements issue

Tags: select, angular5

Really new to Angular and I encountered a strange issue.

I have a list of ingredients and in every ingredient there is a metrics select element.

```
<div class="ingerdients__wrapper" *ngFor="let ingredient of ingredientsList">

<div class="ingerdients__amount-wrapper">

  <p>Amount</p>

  <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="ingredient.amount">

</div>

<div class="ingerdients__amount-wrapper">

  <p>Unit</p>

  <select [(ngModel)]="ingredient.metric.id"  id="Metric_{{ingredient.metric.id}}" name="Metric_{{ingredient.metric.id}}">
    <option *ngFor="let metric of metricsList" [ngValue]="metric.id">{{metric.name}}</option>
  </select>

</div>

<div class="ingerdients__desc-wrapper">

  <textarea cols="30"
            rows="3"
            placeholder="Description"
            [(ngModel)]="ingredient.name"
            (keydown.Tab)="addIngredientToList()"
  ></textarea>

</div>

<div class="ingerdients__add-ingredient-btn-mob-warpper">
  <div class="ingerdients__add-ingredient-btn-warpper mgr" (click)="addIngredientToList()">
    <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="ingerdients__add-ingredient-btn-warpper" (click)="deleteIngredientFromList(n)">
    <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything works fine until I add a new ingredient using function:

```
addIngredientToList() {
this.ingredientsList.push(this.createNewIngredient());}
```

What happens is that when I change values of a metric on an ingredient , it will change the other selection on other ingredients on the list.

I can get it to work normally by doing a submit of the page after I create new ingredients on the list. 
Got any ideas on whats causing this issue? Any advice greatly appreciated.